# AngularJS Directive wrapper leaking memory with Kendo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, kendo-ui

Been at this for a bit so I'm looking for some outside help now.  The basic gist is we're using Kendo in our application but we want to create directive wrappers for each of the built in kendo directives that are provided.  This allows to override functionality and handle things how we want to in a more reusable format for our application.  That said, I am noticing some memory leak errors that I don't get when using the straight kendo-drop-down-list directive.

The plunkr of this example can be accessed here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/SXhrkGbMnRRgDjI3v2kR?p=preview

Below contains the markup I am looking to achieve with overrides to functionality inside the directive's controller.

```
 <div dir-custom-dropdown="row.controls.customDDL" data-text-field="textfield" 
                data-value-field="textfield" data-datasource="row.dsSearchAndOr" data-ng-model="row.properties.searchAndOr"></select>
```

The recreatable steps I've used is two create 2 new rows by clicking add row on the first two rows.  Click remove row on the second row twice to get back down to one row.  Take a heap snapshot in Chrome dev tools, repeat the process 2 more times, then do a comparison of objects allocated between Snapshot 1 and 2.  There is much more information still allocated and I'm kinda confused what could be holding it.

Example of the screen and leftovers can be found here too for comparison:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UdeX.jpg

I tried keeping a reference of the kendo-drop-down-list at one point and calling its method manually but got an error on this line of the destroy in kendo.all.js:

that._arrow.off();

_arrow is undefined.  So I'm not sure if there's a recommended way to clean this up or this is just not supported but we really do need to have wrappers for the kendo directives to customize to our applications needs.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong when creating the isolate scope for the drop down but that is the path I want to go down.  Anything glaringly noticeable that I'm not doing to cleanup would be great.

Comment: I might have it figured out. In $scope.$on("$destroy", function(), I have to manually call the kendo's destroy method.  I was running into problems with this because I was tracking ng-repeat by $index instead of a row.id value.  Scopes were getting destroyed when new items were added.  I will write up a full answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem with kendo ui widgets and memory leaks. Our case was specifically related to routing. Any kendo widgets from a prior route would never get cleaned up when the new route generated new HTML and thus we had a memory leak.

One fix that worked was to clean up existing HTML before a route change. So wherever we change to a new route via:

```
$location.path('/my/new/route')
```

we execute some extra code to clear out the HTML in the prior view using:

```
kendo.destroy(document.body);
$('.view-root-node').html('');
```

The first line cleans up any kendo widgets in the HTML. The second line also cleaned up anything else that may have been missed, including orphaned event handlers, etc. The combination made sure that memory stays constant even under load.

... and that solved it for us.